# Python Selenium save list items as array

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Python Selenium to look through some HTML and find elements.  I have the following HTML saved into Python...

```
<section id="categories">
    <ul id="category_list">
        <li id="category84">
            <a href="www.example.com/samplelink">Sample Category</a>
        </li>
        <li id="category984">
            <a href="www.example.com/samplelink44">Another Category</a>
        </li>
        <li id="category22">
            <a href="www.example.com/samplelink">My Sample Category</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I can find the categories section easy enough but now I would like to loop through each list item and save it's name and href link into an array.

Anyone got a similar example I can see?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, let's use a [CSS selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_css_selector) locator and a list comprehension calling `.get_attribute("href")` to get the link and `.text` to get the link text:

```
categories = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#categories #category_list li[id^=category] a")

result = [{"link": category.get_attribute("href"), "text": category.text} 
          for category in categories]
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, great example!